# Selenium python multiple button clicks on a page NOT working

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, button, click

I cannot find a way to click all the buttons with text 'more' on this page (https://religiondatabase.org/browse/regions). I have tried following ways.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains



chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')


driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://religiondatabase.org/browse/regions')

# Wait for the page to load
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Find all buttons containing the text "more"
buttons = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'more')]")))
print(buttons)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

for button in buttons:
    actions.click(button).perform()
```

This method clicks the first button, then for the next button I get the error message:

```
Message: move target out of bounds
```

To counter this, I tried using the coordinates for clicking and scrolling into view using javascript as below:

```
for button in buttons:
    coordinates = button.location_once_scrolled_into_view # returns dict of X, Y coordinates
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo({}, {});'.format(coordinates['x'], coordinates['y']))
    button.click()
```

This resulted in the following error:

```
Element is not clickable at point(x,y)
```

I also tried using javascript for executing the click as recommended on many stackoverflow posts, still  no luck:

```
for i in range(len(buttons)):
    buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'more')]")
    button = buttons[i]
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

This gives the following error:

```
Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Comment: You realize that you are trying to click over 1,000 buttons?

Comment: It is a very big page, I agree. This is my first webscraping project, I thought I could make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You had the basic concept but there are a few issues with trying to click that many buttons on that large of a page. I had to use a custom `click()` method to handle the timings and intermittent exceptions.

This code is working.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import (ElementClickInterceptedException,
                                        StaleElementReferenceException)
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


def click(locator, timeout_in_seconds):
    timeout = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=timeout_in_seconds)
    while datetime.now() < timeout:
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, timeout_in_seconds).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator)).click()
        except (ElementClickInterceptedException, StaleElementReferenceException):
            # do nothing, loop again
            pass

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://religiondatabase.org/browse/regions')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
locator = (By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'more')]")

for button in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located(locator)):
    click(locator, 5)

print("Done")
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I still get a timeout at the end. After scrolling all the way to the end of the page, I get : selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
I tried increasing the timeout_in_seconds to 10, but that didn't do anything. Is there a condition we can put for reaching the end of page?